# remove extra Woocommerce product title from Genesis

Tags: woocommerce, genesis

We're using a child theme of Genesis.

`woocommerce.php` contains:

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Template
 * 
 * Template used for all WooCommerce views for your site
 *
 */

//* Remove standard post content output
remove_action('genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop');

//* Add WooCommerce content output
add_action('genesis_loop', 'woocommerce_setup_genesis' );

genesis();
```

`functions.php` contains:

```
function woocommerce_setup_genesis() {
  woocommerce_content();
}
add_theme_support( 'woocommerce' );
```

On the front end product page, we receive:

```
<main class="content" id="genesis-content">Core
  <div class="archive-description taxonomy-archive-description taxonomy-description">
    <h1 class="archive-title">Core</h1>
  </div>
```

Note the `Core` in:

```
<main class="content" id="genesis-content">Core
```

This duplicates the product title.

I'd like to know how to remove this duplicate, without hiding `<h1 class="archive-title">`, preferably using `remove_action` in `woocommerce.php`.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the "Genesis Connect for WooCommerce plugin" that is available from Studiopress? It's supposed to optimize WooCommerce templates by using it's own archive, single and tax templates that allow use of genesis hooks.